# How to calculate the sum of prices in a cart JList?

Tags: java, swing, jlist

I have been creating this inventory program that gets the product ID, name, item price and stocks from a txt file. It imports it to my product list (`JList`), then when I press the "add to cart" button, it will then move the selected product to the Cart (which is another `JList`).

My main question is, how can I calculate the sum of all of the prices in the Cart? How do I bind the prices of the product items with a specific price? Assuming that to show the total price, I'm using a `JLabel`.

Here are some pictures and code:

[My inventory program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D4YfC.png)

This is the code for the move button as of now:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource() == movebutton) {
    model2.addElement(list.getSelectedValue());

    }
```

This is the code to show the images, item name, price and stock of an item:

```
public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
    try {
        String gadgets = (String) c1.getSelectedItem();  //when the combobox is selected
        switch (gadgets) {
            case "Consoles":  //selects first product category
                image.setIcon(graphicsconsole[list.getSelectedIndex()]);  //sets the image

                File file = new File("stock\\consoles\\consoles.txt"); //reads the txt file 
                int ctr = 0;
                try {
                    Scanner s1 = new Scanner(new File(String.valueOf(file)));
                    while (s1.hasNextLine()) {
                        ctr = ctr + 1;
                        s1.next();
                        s1.next();
                        s1.next();
                        s1.nextLine();
                    }
                    String[] ID = new String[ctr];
                    String[] PRICE = new String[ctr];
                    String[] STOCK = new String[ctr];
                    String[] NAME = new String[ctr];

                    Scanner s2 = new Scanner(new File(String.valueOf(file)));  //creates strings
                    for (int i = 0; i < ctr; i = i + 1) {
                        ID[i] = s2.next();
                        PRICE[i] = s2.next();
                        STOCK[i] = s2.next();
                        NAME[i] = s2.nextLine();

                iteminfo.setText(NAME[list.getSelectedIndex()]);  //shows the item name
                itemdescription.setText(" P " + PRICE[list.getSelectedIndex()]);  //shows the price
                itemstock.setText(" Stock: "+ STOCK[list.getSelectedIndex()]); //shows the stock
                    }
                } catch (Exception a) {
                    a.printStackTrace();
                }break;
```

Do I need to have an empty array and add the values there? How do I also remove values when it is not in the cart? Sorry if my post/question sounds confusing, I hope that it is understandable.

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Hard code data for the list.

Comment: Your information should not be kept in JLisits.  Your information should be kept in model classes, plain old Java classes separate from the ListModel.

Comment: Well normally when you have a shopping cart you would keep the product, price and quantity information in the shopping cart. So this would mean you would use a `JTable` (not a JList) to display the shopping cart. If you want to know the total price, you then loop through all the rows of the table and total the amount.

Comment: @camickr Hello! Thank you for the suggestion, I might try that :)